# How to get the value of a specific nested XML element using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have the XML like this

```
    <Root>
      <NodeA>
        <NodeA1>
          <NodeA11>
            <SameNameNode>
              <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 1</SameNameNodeChild1>
              <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 2</SameNameNodeChild2>
            </SameNameNode>
          </NodeA11>
        </NodeA1>
      </NodeA>
      <NodeB>
        <SameNameNode>
          <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 3</SameNameNodeChild1>
          <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 4</SameNameNodeChild2>
        </SameNameNode>
      </NodeB>
      <NodeC>
        <NodeC1>
          <SameNameNode>
            <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 5</SameNameNodeChild1>
            <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 6</SameNameNodeChild2>
          </SameNameNode>
        </NodeC1>
      </NodeC>
   </Root>
```

As you can see the "SameNameNode" and its childs appear at a few places at different level of nesting but the names are the same. How do I get the element values of "Value 1" and "Value 2" only using LINQ to XML.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some complete sample code that will grab the values:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<Root>
<NodeA>
<NodeA1>
    <NodeA11>
    <SameNameNode>
        <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 1</SameNameNodeChild1>
        <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 2</SameNameNodeChild2>
    </SameNameNode>
    </NodeA11>
</NodeA1>
</NodeA>
<NodeB>
<SameNameNode>
    <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 3</SameNameNodeChild1>
    <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 4</SameNameNodeChild2>
</SameNameNode>
</NodeB>
<NodeC>
<NodeC1>
    <SameNameNode>
    <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 5</SameNameNodeChild1>
    <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 6</SameNameNodeChild2>
    </SameNameNode>
</NodeC1>
</NodeC>
</Root>");

    var results = xdoc.Root
        .Elements("NodeA")
        .Elements("NodeA1")
        .Elements("NodeA11")
        .Elements("SameNameNode")
        .Descendants()
        .Select(e => new { ElementName = e.Name, ElementValue = e.Value });

    foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Value = {1}", result.ElementName, result.ElementValue);
    }
```

This will output:

```
Name = SameNameNodeChild1, Value = Value 1
Name = SameNameNodeChild2, Value = Value 2
```

You may need to tweak the query -- I'm assuming you want all descendants of "SameNameNode", but you may want to filter only certain sub-elements.

@Mun, to answer your question about the LINQ query syntax, you can do the same thing with this code.  The 2 pieces of code are equivalent:

```
var results = from nodeAElem in xdoc.Root.Elements("NodeA")
               from nodeA1Elem in nodeAElem.Elements("NodeA1")
               from nodeA11Elem in nodeA1Elem.Elements("NodeA11")
               from sameNameNodeElem in nodeA11Elem.Elements("SameNameNode").Descendants()
               select new { ElementName = sameNameNodeElem.Name, ElementValue = sameNameNodeElem.Value };
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you JohnD. But instead of just the values of the nodes in the result list, how can I get also the node names, like "SameNameNodeChild1" "Value 1"

Comment: Hi, I updated the sample to use an anonymous type (the new {} syntax) and print out the element name as well as the value.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you again JohnD. But one thing I want to ask if there is any difference from your query with other query which use Linq like "from p in Xdoc.Elements() select ....". I am just a little bit confused since I am new to Linq and only learn from the net.

Comment: I added another sample for you using the linq query syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much @JohnD. Is there any online articles about Linq which you can recommend?

Comment: I don't have any specific online recommendations, but I really liked the books "LINQ in Action" (Marguerie, Eichert and Wooley) as well as "C# in Depth" (Skeet)

Comment: I have use this query of yours     var results = xdoc.Root
        .Elements("NodeA")
        .Elements("NodeA1")
        .Elements("NodeA11")
        .Elements("SameNameNode")
        .Descendants()
        .Select(e => new { ElementName = e.Name, ElementValue = e.Value }); <br /> but I add the where clause like this <BR /> .Where (e => e.Name.Equals("SameNameNodeChild1")), I got no result back. Did I do something wrong? Thank you.