# Get value from nested XML element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to search for the text value of `<code>` of Accountants under a job category Accounting.

Below is the idea I am thinking to get this value, but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to access the value of `<code>`?

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var accountants = from c in xml.Root.Elements("JobCategory") 
                  where c.Elements("Name").Equals("Accounting") 
                  select c;
var code = from c in accountants.Descendants("Code")
           select c;
```

I am using asp.net MVC. The `xmlString` is like this:

```
<JobCategories xmlns="http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <JobCategory>
  <Name>Accounting</Name>
  <Code>5001</Code>
  <SubCategories>
     <JobCategory>
       <Name>Accountants</Name>
       <Code>5002</Code>
     </JobCategory>
     <JobCategory>
       <Name>Accounts administrators</Name>
       <Code>5007</Code>
     </JobCategory>
  </SubCategories>
  </JobCategory>

  <JobCategory>
  <Name>Agriculture, fishing &amp; forestry</Name>
  <Code>5015</Code>
  <SubCategories>
     <JobCategory>
       <Name>Farming</Name>
       <Code>5016</Code>
     </JobCategory>
     <JobCategory>
       <Name>Fishing</Name>
       <Code>5017</Code>
     </JobCategory>
  </SubCategories>
  </JobCategory>

</JobCategories>
```

Comment: Please give a sample input and desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicates check this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939168/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-specific-nested-xml-element-using-linq-to-xml) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821410/how-to-retrieve-element-values-of-nested-elements-in-xml-with-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of issues

First your xml content is in a namespace but you don't use any of them in your code. If you want to access elements by name, you have to reference those names correctly.

The expression `c.Elements("Name").Equals("Accounting")` is nonsense. You're attempting to get the child elements called `Name` and comparing if that collection is equal to the string `"Accounting"`. That clearly makes no sense at all.

Assuming you're just getting the `Code` values of the elements, you'd do this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1";
var codes =
    from jc in doc.Root.Elements(ns + "JobCategory")
    select (string)jc.Element(ns + "Code");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - that's really helpful and gives me the idea to do what I need. I'm trying to get the `<code>` value of a particular job type under a particular job category depends on the user input. So if the user select "Accounting > Accounts administrators", it should return its `<code>` value 5002.

Comment: And I do something like:
`var list = from jc in xml.Root.Elements(ns + "JobCategory") where jc.Element(ns + "Name").Value == "Accounting" select jc.Element(ns + "SubCategories");`
     , then...    `var code = from j in list.Elements(ns + "JobCategory") where j.Element(ns + "Name").Value == "Accounts administrators" select (string)j.Element(ns + "Code");`  However, is there anyway to shorten the code to do the same thing?